# Display specific div class of web page with webview android

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I have tried serveral examples from Stackoverflow like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementById('idName')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "})()");
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("url");
    }
}
```

This example is to hide an specific ID (I know..), but this doesn't work either.. It still displays the whole web page.

I only want a specific div to display which have an unique class name.

Comment: can you put your code in onPageFinished override method   webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" + "document.getElementById('idName').style.display ='none';" + "})()");

Comment: I already use onPageFinished?